# Почему поле не добавилось в базу данных? Как получить данные из связанной таблицы postgres?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Вот какая проблема.

**Есть 2 модели**

```
class RelationType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class RelationRequest(models.Model):
    type_of_relation = models.ManyToManyField(RelationType, related_name='type_relation',
        verbose_name=_('type_relation'))
```

То есть `RelationRequest` через МТМ свзяан с `RelationType`. `type_of_relation` приходит в модель из мультиселекта. Вот представление:

**views.py**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        relation_form = RelationRequestForm(request.POST or None)
        if relation_form.is_valid():
            for rt in relation_form.cleaned_data['type_of_relation']:
                relation_user_id = int(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), request.path))
                rq = RelationRequest.objects.create(
                    creator = request.user,
                    relation = User.objects.get(id = relation_user_id),
                )
                rq.type_of_relation.add(rt)
```

Когда я смотрю на запись в админке, все поля заполнены верно. Но когда я пытаюсь получить поле `type_of_relation` с помощью

```
request_relation = RelationRequest.objects.filter(creator=user.creator).filter(status=True).first().type_of_relation
```

я получаю `None`. Смотрю в бд таблицу **accounts_relationrequest** - там этого поля вовсе нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зато есть таблица **accounts_relationrequest_type_of_relation**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем, нужно как-то, зная `id` записи `RelationRequest` получать значение `type_of_relation`.

А вообще, по-хорошему, нужно убрать эту таблицу и добавить поле с `type_of_relation`.

Но как это сделать, не знаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значение `type_of_relation` в зависимости от необходимого формата можно получить

либо так:

```
request_relation = RelationRequest.objects.filter(creator=user.creator).filter(status=True).values('type_of_relation')
```

`QuerySet` будет содержать пары из <"type_of_relation": RelationType id> для записей RelationRequest которые соответствуют условиям фильтра.

либо так:

```
request_relation = RelationRequest.objects.filter(creator=user.creator).filter(status=True).values_list('type_of_relation', flat=True)
```

В этом случае в `QuerySet` будет плоский список из id записей `RelationType` для записей `RelationRequest` которые соответствуют условиям фильтра.

Если требуется получить `type_of_relation` для первого объекта `RelationRequest` как в вашем примере, то лучше сделать так:

```
request_relation = RelationRequest.objects.filter(creator=user.creator).\
    filter(status=True).prefetch_related('type_of_relation').first()
```

и после `request_relation.type_of_relation.all()` получите `QuerySet` с необходимыми объектами.

Таблица `accounts_relationrequest_type_of_relation` создаётся автоматически для связи `m2m`, удалять её не стоит.

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то. Мне нужно для одной конкретной записи. Я ведь не зря указал `first()`. Это есть последняя изменённая (сохранённая запись), так как сортировка идёт по обновлениям...

Comment: Спасибо. Подправил Ваш ответ.

Comment: Обновил ответ примером для одного объекта RelationRequest.

Comment: Можете объяснить, почему при просмотре `values()` или `values_list()` этих значений не видно, но они там есть, оказывается...?

Comment: Необходимо вместо `id` получить список значений?

Comment: Да неважно что. Просто когда я через принт смотрю в консоле .values() - там нет этих значений... Но Вам удалось их там найти)